# Loop insert binary tree

Tags: c, loops, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm trying to figure out how to insert large amount of numbers into a binary tree.
The program starts off by asking a number and inserts 0 to whatever number the user inputted. My program works but it starts to crash around 40,000 where I get the error:
Process returned -1073741571(0XC00000FD)

I'm new to C and memory management but I believe the issue lies there. any advice?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct node BSTREE;

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node * left;
    struct node * right;
};

void insert(BSTREE ** root, int number);

 int main()
{

    BSTREE *root = malloc(sizeof *root);
    BSTREE *tmp = malloc(sizeof *root);
    root = NULL;
    int x;
    int input;

    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("c:\\test2.txt", "w");


    printf( "Please enter a number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );

    for ( x = 0; x < input; x++ )
    {
    insert(&root, x);
    }
    printf("%d", x);
    free(root);

    fclose(fp);

    }

void insert(BSTREE ** root, long int number)
{

    BSTREE *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*root))
    {
        temp = (BSTREE *)malloc(sizeof(BSTREE));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = number;
        *root = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(number < (*root)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*root)->left, number);
        free(root);
    }
    else if(number > (*root)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*root)->right, number);
        free(root);
    }
 free(root);
   }
```

Comment: `free(root);` at `insert` ?? and might stack overflow.

Comment: `long int number` --> `int number` , `BSTREE *root = malloc(sizeof *root);
    BSTREE *tmp = malloc(sizeof *root);
    root = NULL;` memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `free(root)` twice on every invocation of insert. Once immediately after `insert` returns.  And then immediately on the same node again.  And you seem to be always free'ing the node you just inserted anyway.  Hence, your memory is likely corrupt and just happens to work on small trees.  As your tree gets larger, memory starts to get re-allocated and the tree corruption gets more apparent.

Here's a proposed simpler solution. It's more verbose, but handles the malloc and free in one function, while the core recursive insert is done in another. Hope this helps.

```
extern int insert_node(BSTREE* root, BSTREE* node);

void insert(BSTREE** root, int number)
{
    /* allocate a node for our number to be inserted */
    BSTREE* node = malloc(sizeof(BSTREE));
    node->data = number;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    int insert_result;

    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        /* handle the empty tree case */
        *root = node;
        return;
    }

    insert_result = insert_node(*root, node);

    if (!insert_result)
    {
        /* insert_node returned false.
           This means it already had a duplicate of the node 
           in the tree. Just free it since it did not get inserted
        */
        free(node);
        node = NULL;
    }

}

int insert_node(BSTREE* root, BSTREE* node)
{
    int result = 1; /* success */

    if (node->data < root->data)
    {
        /* traverse left */
        if (node->left != NULL)
        {
            result = insert_node(root->left, node);
        }
        else
        {
            root->left = node;
        }
    }
    else if (node->data > root->data)
    {
        /* traverse right */
        if (node->right != NULL)
        {
            result = insert_node(root->right, node);
        }
        else
        {
            root->right = node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* else node is equal to root - nothing to do */
        /* return 0 to indicate the node should be free'd by the caller*/
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to post your full result I'm still trying to wrap my head around how it works

Comment: What do you mean by *my full result*?  Replace your `insert` function with the code I provided above.  Copy both the `insert` and `insert_node` functions above into your program and remove your implementation of `insert`

Comment: I tried that but your code keeps giving me one 5 digit number in the results so I thought maybe I was missing something.

Comment: Because I forgot to assign `node->data` after `node` was allocated with malloc.  I fixed the code sample above.